# How to get the link using htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

How can I simulate a click on the respective tag `<a>` below and grab the link contained in it?

```
<span class="textAlignment nextPage">
  <a class="jsEnabled nextBtn cursorPointer" href="javascript:setSelectedLink('NextPageButton');" title="Next page" alt="Next page"></a>
</span>
```

---

Using htmlunit as follows to get the element but I only get null

`HtmlAnchor a = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='jsEnabled nextBtn cursorPointer']");`

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate a click you should first fetch the element from the HtmlPage. I would use [`getFirstByXPath`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Then just perform the `click` method on the returned object.

It is unclear what you mean by first clicking in a link and then *grabbing the link contained in it*. If you want to, apart from clicking the anchor, getting the content of the `href` attribute before clicking on it then you should fetch the anchor using the same method mentioned above and before clicking on it perform the [`getHrefAttribute`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlAnchor.html#getHrefAttribute%28%29).

Comment: I need to simulate a click, because the href contains a JScript function that returns a new page

Comment: Actually I just need the url generated